# how to style multiple modals through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select multiple modals through Javascript. I have already set an id on every modal.
So far I am able to loop through the elements but I don't know how to grab every id of modals.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="projects">
            <div data-modal="modal1">
                <div>
                      <p>Coffee</p>
                </div>
                <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div data-modal="modal2">
                <div>
                       <p>Tea</p>
                </div>
                <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
            </div>
      </div>

<div class="project-card" id="modal1">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
        
<div class="project-card" id="modal2">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
const projects = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div');

for(var i = 0; i< projects.length;i++){
    var thisBtn = projects[i];
    thisBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        var modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
}
```

I saw `this.dataset.modal` implement at one of the solutions. But unfortunately, it didn't work. How can I grab that particular id of element when its parent modal is clicked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Code for closing modal when clicking outside:

```
window.addEventListener('click',function(){
    
   for(var i = 0; i<coffeeGrounds.length; i++){
         var x = coffeeGrounds[i].getAttribute('data-modal');
             var a = document.getElementById(x);
                console.log(a);
                if(a.style.display === 'block'){
                      a.setAttribute('style','display:none');
                 }
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open modeal:** The first loop puts "addEventListener" which takes date information with the ID of the modal.

**Close modal:** The second loop takes all the "close" buttons. Puts "addEventListener" when this button is pressed, it applies a style `display:none;` to the parent item

```js
const projects = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div');
for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    projects[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var x = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
        document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    });
}

const close = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var x = this.parentElement;
        x.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">

    <div data-modal="modal1">
        <div>
            <p>Coffee</p>
        </div>
        <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div data-modal="modal2">
        <div>
            <p>Tea</p>
        </div>
        <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="project-card" id="modal1" style="display:none;">
    <button class="close">X</button>
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project-card" id="modal2" style="display:none;">
    <button class="close">X</button>
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I have tried both of your functionalities, the displaying of modal is working flawlessly but the close listener is not quite firing. Been trying this for some time tho, kinda stuck on this, would really appreciate any help.

Comment: In the example I uploaded the modal closing function works. Please review your code and see what the differences are from my example

Comment: If you can't find the problem. Please post your code after the changes you have made in JS, HTML and CSS so that I can be useful.

Comment: Really sorry, my bad I was using querySelector instead of querySelectorAll.Thank you so much.

Comment: If you don't mind I can use your little help, I am trying to close the modal by clicking outside. I am looping through each modal and checking if there is a click on the window, if it is then set the modal display to none. I don't know what I am doing wrong, if you want to see my code I can edit my post. Would really appreciate any help

Comment: Hi, over here by setting the modal display to none. It's holding back to display the modal also.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a solution that works successfully. Try to find a solution by posting a new Question in the SO.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `this` in arrow (`=>`) function syntax, use normal function syntax instead.

**Demo:**

```js
const projects = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div');

for(var i = 0; i < projects.length;i++){
    var thisBtn = projects[i];
    thisBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        console.log('You have clicked: ' +this.dataset.modal);
    }, false);
}
```

```css
.project-card{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
    <div data-modal="modal1">
        <div>
          <p>Coffee</p>
        </div>
        <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div data-modal="modal2">
        <div>
           <p>Tea</p>
        </div>
        <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project-card" id="modal1">
  <button class="close">X</button>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="project-card" id="modal2">
  <button class="close">X</button>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh god, I totally missed this. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.